# jQuery UI no-theme CSS cdn

Tags: css, jquery-ui, google-cdn

I'm looking for the no-theme CSS that you can get on the jQuery UI download page, http://jqueryui.com/download/.

From this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348559/are-there-hosted-jquery-ui-themes-anywhere, I would expect to find it at:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/no-theme/jquery-ui.css

But, a file does not exist there. I'm looking for the no-theme CSS, no images or background-image properties.

The closest one is the base theme, but that has background-images properties for an image located at images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png. Base CSS on CDN:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Is there a URL for the latest version of no-theme jQuery UI CSS?

Answer (score 3):

No, there doesn't seem to be a "no-theme" CSS on Google or MS CDN. However, you could load the individual components (i.e. `jquery.ui.button.css`, `jquery.ui.core.css` etc.) instead of the combined `jquery-ui.css`. Just leave out `jquery.ui.theme.css`!

Google does not provide the individual components, but cdnjs does:
http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui/

So, grab all the

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/minified/jquery.ui.(...).min.css
```

*Except*

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/css/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css
```

In fact, you don't even have to get all components (e.g. if you never use accordion, don't load it).

Note that "base" was renamed "Smoothness" in 1.10.2, but for whatever reason cdnjs has renamed it back to "base"...

However you lose out 2 things: more file requests (although total file size is smaller), and cacheing (vast majority of users will already have the Google version cached).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jQuery mobile.  Using the "structure-only" CSS file will provide functionality without interfering with local CSS.

Add "structure" to the name of the CSS URL like this (for example): 
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css